# How to convert NextStep plist to JSON

Tags: iphone, json

I need to convert NextStep Plist string to JSON format
Is there any library to do?

Comment: What platform do you want this library for?

Answer (score 1):

```
[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:(id) options:(NSJSONWritingOptions) error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)]
```

Comment: Good, but fix your Xcode tags `<# #>`, and maybe link to the docs.

Answer (score 0):

To convert FILENAME From the command line in OS X:

`plutil -convert json -r -e json FILENAME`

This will convert the file to JSON format and give it a .json extension.